# Python: Writing list to xml file

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to write the list elements to an xml file. I have written the below code. The xml file is created, but the data is repeated. I'm unable to figure out why is the data written twice in the xml file.

```
users_list = ['Group1User1', 'Group1User2', 'Group2User1', 'Group2User2']
def create_xml(self):
    usrconfig = Element("usrconfig")
    usrconfig = ET.SubElement(usrconfig,"usrconfig")
    for user in range(len( users_list)):
        usr = ET.SubElement(usrconfig,"usr")
        usr.text = str(users_list[user])
    usrconfig.extend(usrconfig)
    tree = ET.ElementTree(usrconfig)
    tree.write("details.xml",encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Output File: details.xml

-

```
<usr>Group1User1</usr>

<usr>Group1User2</usr>

<usr>Group2User1</usr>

<usr>Group2User2</usr>

<usr>Group1User1</usr>

<usr>Group1User2</usr>

<usr>Group2User1</usr>

<usr>Group2User2</usr>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA8MR.png)

Comment: I think this package can be useful  for you [xmljson](https://pypi.org/project/xmljson/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usrconfig.extend(usrconfig)
```

This line looks suspicious to me. if `userconfig` was a list, this line would be equivalent to "duplicate every element in this list". I suspect that something similar happens for Elements, too. Try deleting that line.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

users_list = ["Group1User1", "Group1User2", "Group2User1", "Group2User2"]

def create_xml():
        usrconfig = ET.Element("usrconfig")
        usrconfig = ET.SubElement(usrconfig,"usrconfig")
        for user in range(len( users_list)):
                usr = ET.SubElement(usrconfig,"usr")
                usr.text = str(users_list[user])
        tree = ET.ElementTree(usrconfig)
        tree.write("details.xml",encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)

create_xml()
```

Result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<usrconfig>
<usr>Group1User1</usr>
<usr>Group1User2</usr>
<usr>Group2User1</usr>
<usr>Group2User2</usr>
</usrconfig>
```

Comment: usrconfig.extend(usrconfig)  was causing the issue. Deleting this line solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple xml structure, we can directly write out the file. But this technique might also be useful if one is not up to speed with the python xml modules.

```
import os

users_list = ["Group1User1", "Group1User2", "Group2User1", "Group2User2"]
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop")
xml_out_DD = open("test.xml", 'wb')
xml_out_DD.write(bytes('<usrconfig>', 'utf-8'))
for i in range(0, len(users_list)):
    xml_out_DD.write(bytes('<usr>'  + users_list[i] + '</usr>', 'utf-8'))
xml_out_DD.write(bytes('</usrconfig>', 'utf-8'))
xml_out_DD.close()
```